# How Can I Show All Hidden Columns In ObjectListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, objectlistview

My current ObjectListView has around 50 columns (30 of which are hidden by default).  I want to add an option that allows the user to press a button and be presented with ALL columns visible.

Currently I can only find code that allows me to manually turn on each individual column one at a time:

```
MainColumn.IsVisible = False
ListView1.RebuildColumns()
```

However, it doesn't explain how to turn on all columns in one go.

I have tried using:

```
For Each c as OLVColumn In ListView1.Columns
c.IsVisible = True
Next
ListView1.RebuildColumns()
```

However, that seems to just loop through the visible columns so I don't get any change.

Thanks

Comment: is it windows or web question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to visible all columns in a single property assignment. You have to visible all invisible column loop through. The example you have given in your question is correct but, you just need to add more condition to make it faster.

```
var columns = (From col As OLVColumn in ListView1.Columns 
               Where col.IsVisible = False).ToArray()
For Each header As OLVColumn IN columns
    header.Visible = True
```

```
For I As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
    IF Not ListView1.Columns(I).IsVisible Then
         ListView1.Columns(I).IsVisible = True
    End IF
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Shell, any chance you could post a VB equivalent as the code convertors don't seem to like the conversion.

Comment: Also @Shell, is your code ObjectListView compliant because ColumnHeader isn't a recognized command for that control?

Comment: I'm assuming the code converts over to something like: 
        `Dim columns as OLVColumn = (From col As OLVColumn In lsv_Objects.Columns Where col.IsVisible = False).ToArray()

        For Each header As OLVColumn In columns
            header.Visible = True
        Next`

Which gives an error of: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn'

Comment: this bcoz the `BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView` is not the `Windows Form Control`. let me download the `ObjectListView` try it my self.

Comment: Unfortunately `BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.Columns` could not be taken in LINQ query. Im really surprised why they have not created separate OLVColumn Collection for that? BTW, So I don't think so that you have any other choice instead of for loop.

Comment: it seems that `Columns` does not support the `IsVisible` flag.  As far as I can see, it is only supported on `ColumnsInDisplayOrder` but that only seems to include Visible column headers.  There is a `ColumnHeaderCollection` but I can't see how to integrate the `IsVisible` flag into that.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... Works if you use `AllColumns` instead of `Columns`

```
foreach (OLVColumn col in olv.AllColumns) {
   col.IsVisible = true;
}
```